# How to keep original text color with PSfrag?

Tags: psfrag

I would like to know if there is a way to keep text color unchanged while giving a replacement within `\psfrag`. I have an electric circuit where some identical text labels should be displayed at the same time in two different colors (black and gray).

```
Original EPS:        `\psfrag{R11}{$R_{11}$}`   PSfrag:
R11 (in gray color)  -----------------------> `$R_{11}$` (in gray color)
R11 (in black color) -----------------------> `$R_{11}$` (in black color)
```

Comment: Could you show the example image? Because, for instance, you can have multiple labels (if they are at different locations) and use `....{\color{...}sub1}` instead.

Comment: if the labels are identical you can not separate them with psfrag, but you can re-generate with arbitrary label text L1 and L2 say and then replace L1 by a gray `R_11` and L2 by a black `R_11`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This is exactly what I think for a workaround

Comment: you provided no example, normally I'd expect a psfrag replacement to keep the original colour by default, but it depends on the details of the PostScript in the file.

Comment: The PostScript was generated from a PS printer, the circuit is complicated and PS code is awkward to read, the only thing I should do is replaced each |`xshow` definition given by `[N N N]xS` by `show` in order to be recognized by PSfrag. Also to keep the original labels as such I append each tag name having gray color with an empty space.